# How to copy in Excel 2016 a cell with hyperlink from one sheet to another using formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, hyperlink, cells

I am automating an excel based report and need a formula that will take cell `A2` with its `hyperlink` from Sheet2 and copy it to another column in Sheet 1. Hyperlink points to external web address. When I use just `=A2` it copies the text but without the hyperlink.

How to do this? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The below will work:

`=HYPERLINK(MID(FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A2),SEARCH("www.",FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A2)),SEARCH(".com",FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A2))-SEARCH("www.",FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A2))+4),"Click")`

It uses `FORMULATEXT`, to display the hyperlink as text, the `SEARCH` to find the stat an end of the link, and then `MID` to recreate the link,

Thne wrap the whole thing in `HYPERLINK`

This will only work on links starting with `www.` and ending `.com`

you can change it to suit the link you have in your sheet.

**Note. FORMULATEXT is availiable for excel 2016**

Comment: Hello, I cannot make it work. My link is very complex - it points to an object in SAP related tool located in company intranet and includes redirect. I receive NA when trying to change values for link start and end in the formula

Comment: what does the link start and end with ?

Comment: link end: OBJECT_ID&crm-object-value=9000272438

Comment: for every cell in the source column the number in the end is different and I want to be able to expand the formula with dragging down in destination column

Comment: link start update: globe7.